# IBM Watson Text to Speech API Python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I'm trying to adjust the pitch of IBM Watson but I can't seem to find any documentation on this whatsoever.

[If you visit this link](https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/tts-demo/self-service/home) then you can see that there is an option to adjust the pitch/speed.

The code I have is very simply this:

```
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('api_key')
text_to_speech = TextToSpeechV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)

text_to_speech.set_service_url('service_url')

sample = "insert what you want to say here"

with open('test.wav', 'wb') as audio_file:
    audio_file.write(
        text_to_speech.synthesize(
            sample,
            voice='en-GB_JamesV3Voice',
            accept='audio/wav'
        ).get_result().content)
```

I have literally no idea what parameters to adjust in order to make the voice low. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [prosody element](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-elements#prosody_element). Neural voices (V3) only use the **pitch** and **rate** attribute.

Using your example:

```
sample = 'Here is a <prosody pitch="150Hz"> modified pitch </prosody> example.'

sample = 'Here is a <prosody rate="x-slow"> modified rate </prosody> example.'
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a link to the docs about the `prosody` element:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-elements#prosody_element